# Java using Jconnect

Tags: java, jconnect

Good day!

In order to access the mysql server, I used the JConnect and my code is as follows:

```
  public AddBooks() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/catalog";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","upittc");
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO books VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)");

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exc.getMessage());
        }
        initComponents();
    }
```

To put the data in the database, I used the following code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      try {
              stmt.setString(1, jTextField0.getText()); 
              stmt.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
              stmt.setString(3, jTextField2.getText());
              stmt.setString(4, jTextField3.getText());
              stmt.setString(5, jTextField4.getText());
              stmt.setString(6, Jan2.getSelectedItem().toString());
              stmt.setString(7, Jan3.getSelectedItem().toString());
              stmt.setString(8, jTextField5.getText());
              stmt.setString(9, jTextField6.getText());
              stmt.setString(10, jTextField8.getText());
              stmt.executeUpdate();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save Successful!");

      } catch (Exception ex) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }
}
```

But there's an error on row 1. **COLUMN COUNT DOESN'T MATCH THE VALUE AT ROW** What does it mean?
Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please mention the error and the stacktrace.

Comment: you should change your insert statement to specify the columns you are adding in because the first one is auto-increment and you don't want to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is auto-increment, you should not assign anything to it, remove it from your SQL prepared statement string and just set everything else, the auto increment will do the job by itself.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...) ");
```

get rid of first column to have:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_name (column2, column3,...) VALUES ( value2, value3,...) ");
```

and replace values with question marks and set them as you do later on.

```
          stmt.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
          stmt.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
          stmt.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
          stmt.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
          stmt.setString(5, Jan2.getSelectedItem().toString());
          stmt.setString(6, Jan3.getSelectedItem().toString());
          stmt.setString(7, jTextField5.getText());
          stmt.setString(8, jTextField6.getText());
          stmt.setString(9, jTextField8.getText());
          stmt.executeUpdate();
```

NOTICE: decremented indices (the number of the question mark value).

Hope that helps!